# FCM: unable to signup, showing OPERATION NOT ALLOWED exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was trying to register with FCM, but it was showing OPERATION NOT ALLOWED error at the time of registration.

Also showing following in error log

> Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"

Comment: Did you forgot to share the problematic code? Or was there no code involved?

Comment: Maybe add your dependencies as well.